# Query Google Firestore for multiple IDs at once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently writing an android app. In my app users can rate some objects. The data (the objects as well as the ratings) are stored in Google Firebase, especially Firestore.

---

The data is saved to the database like:

```
SomeObject: | objectId | name |

ObjectRating: | ratingId | objectId | userId | rating |
```

---

In the app I want to query all the ratings of a user and the objects data.
So at first I query all the ratings by the unserId, to get the ratings of the current user. Next I collect the objectIds of the objects rated by the user.

Then I want to get all the corresponding objects.
I dont know how to query Firestore for a collection of objectIds at once.
I do not want to query all the objectIds separately, to reduce the number of queries.

Is there a possibility to query for multiple Ids at once in Firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android SDK doesn't support a `BatchGet` method at this time, so unfortunately you'll need to get each object individually.